# sql join repeating results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to make a list printing all the clients ordered by the gym name, but it's repeating the gym name the same number of gym's clients. If `gym1` have 4 clients, the `echo` is printed 4 times.

The tables/columns are:

`members (id, gym, name, etc...)`

and

```
gym (gymID, gym_name, etc...).
```

`member.gym` is to know to what `gym` the client belongs (`gym.gymID`)

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("  SELECT DISTINCT g.*, m.*
                                FROM gym g
                                INNER JOIN members m ON m.gym = g.gymID")) {

    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        echo 'Sport center: ' . $row['gym_name'] . '<br>';
        // here print the gym's clients list
    }

}
```

`DISTINCT` is not working... What is the problem??

Comment: [Maybe this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join).

Comment: DISTINCT will report unique rows, not unique column values. So if gym 1 has 4 users (1,2,3,4) then it will report 1,1 then 1,2 then 1,3 then 1,4 since there are no duplicates in the rows returned.

Comment: The SQL is working correctly.  That is *exactly* what the query should be returning.  You are misunderstanding the SQL language and specifically what `DISTINcT` does.

Comment: What result *did* you actually expect?

Comment: I expected to print the gym_name and the gym clients.

Comment: @ChazyChaz Which layout you want? Because what you're getting is exactly what it's supposed to happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the normal behavior.

**Example.**

Consider the following tables

```
Table "gym"
-----------
gym_id | gym_name
-------+----------
  1    |  Gym A
  2    |  Gym B

Table "members"
---------------
member_id | gym_id | member_name
----------+--------+------------
  1       |  1     | Bob
  2       |  1     | Jeff
```

And now, execute this query:

```sql
select g.gym_id, g.gim_name, m.member_id, m.member_name
from gym as g
     inner join members as m on g.gym_id = m.gym_id;
```

Result:

```
gym_id | gym_name | member_id | member_name
-------+----------+-----------+-------------
  1    |  Gym A   |   1       |   Bob
  1    |  Gym B   |   2       |   Jeff
```

That happens because each row in the `gym` table is matched with a row in the `members` name. Even if you use `select distinct`, the result would be the same, because every row is different.

I think what you want is an output like this:

```
 Gym A
      Bob
      Jeff
```

Although that can be done directly in SQL, it's easier to handle it directly with PHP, because doing it in SQL <strike>would be a real pain in the neck</strike> would require writing quite a complex query. I'm not quite good with PHP, but it could be something like this:

```php
/*
 You don't need "DISTINCT", but you need "ORDER BY" to make this work
 */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("  SELECT g.*, m.*
                                FROM gym g
                                INNER JOIN members m ON m.gym = g.gymID
                                ORDER BY g.gymID")) {

    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $gym = "";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
        if($row['gym_name'] != $gym)
            echo 'Sport center: ' . $row['gym_name'] . '<br>';
        echo '   Member: ' . $row['member_name'] . '<br>';
        $gym = $row['gym_name'];
    }

}
```

Comment: Best and most complete answer! I like this way! Thank you!

Comment: @ChazyChaz Happy to help. Of course, if you want to list also the gyms without members, you can use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

First, drop the `DISTINCT` and slap in an `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT g.*, m.*
FROM gym g
INNER JOIN members m ON m.gym = g.gymID
ORDER BY g.name;
```

Now, adjust your PHP code to only print the gym name if it's different from the last gym you printed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT g.*, m.*
FROM gym g
INNER JOIN members m ON m.gym = g.gymID
ORDER BY g.name,gym_clients;
```

I dont know the name of Gym Name column & gym Client Column So, Please Change the name if they are not correctly spelled.
I hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM gym g
LEFT JOIN members m 
     ON g.gym_ID=m.gym_id 
GROUP BY g.gym_name
```

Comment: Is that even valid MySQL syntax? I'm asking you because I'm trying to test it in [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d020a/3) and it doesn't work

Comment: @Barranka I answered according to what I saw on your question. The date on your question is not the same as on your SQL fiddle. Now I checked your SQL fiddle. Please try my update.

Comment: It's not *my* question (check the OP's name and mine)! I posted my comment because I'm almost sure that it was not a valid syntax for MySQL (or any SQL dialect). But now you've edited your answer and removed that weird thing. Anyway... `LEFT JOIN` would make no difference to the OP, since the "problem" is that the output is not what he expected, but that has nothing to do with the SQL, but with the front-end program